# Pressing enter in form does not submit as expected

Tags: html, forms

i was given a ready made page that has a contact us form. i made it functional by adding the form verification and the php send email. http://mdscomputers.ae/new/aruba/form.html has the original form and it works perfectly

I liked that form so i used it in another website that i am making. the original form had some extra stuff that i dont need so i removed them when i transferred the form to the other website. the coding of the form in the other website is:-

i have 2 problems:-

1) in the original form when i pressed enter in a field the form submits. in the modified form in the other website pressing enter in a field does nothing and i need press on the submit button to submit the form. i guess there is some coding in the other website which is disabling submit when enter is pressed. i want to be able to submit by pressing enter

2) in the original form the action is working ok and it is opening the page that i specified when i submit the form. in the modified form in the other website i am getting a page not found error when i press submit and it is not opening the page that i specified in the action. for now i want to open the contactus page when the form is submitted

the other website is http://mdscomputers.ae/new/buyback/buyback.html and the modified form is at the bottom of the page

```html
<div class="mktoForm" id="elqForm">
  <form id="elqForm" method="post" name="elqForm" action="contactus.php">
    <div class="elqFormRow">
      <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;">
        <a name="eiel1718959"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <label for="Contact_First_Name"><strong>First Name</strong> *:</label>
      <input type="text" required="required" id="Contact_First_Name" name="Contact_First_Name" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="elqFormRow">
      <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;">
        <a name="eiel1718960"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <label for="Contact_Last_Name"><strong>Last Name</strong> *:</label>
      <input type="text" required="required" id="Contact_Last_Name" name="Contact_Last_Name" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="elqFormRow">
      <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;">
        <a name="eiel1718961"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <label for="Contact_Email"><strong>Business Email</strong> *:</label>
      <input type="text" required="required" pattern="[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$" id="Contact_Email" name="Contact_Email" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="elqFormRow">
      <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;">
        <a name="eiel1718962"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <label for="Job_Responsibility"><strong>Job Title</strong> *:</label>
      <input type="text" required="required" id="Job_Responsibility" name="Job_Responsibility" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="elqFormRow">
      <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;">
        <a name="eiel1718963"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <label for="Company_Name"><strong>Company Name</strong> *:</label>
      <input type="text" required="required" id="Company_Name" name="Company_Name" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="elqFormRow">
      <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;">
        <a name="eiel1718964"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <label for="Company_Country"><strong>Country</strong> *:</label>
      <input type="text" required="required" id="Company_Country" name="Company_Country" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="elqFormRow">
      <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;">
        <a name="eiel1718965"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <label for="Company_State_Province"><strong>City</strong> *:</label>
      <input type="text" required="required" id="Company_State_Province" name="Company_State_Province" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="elqFormRow">
      <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;">
        <a name="eiel1718966"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <label for="Contact_Phone_Number"><strong>Business Phone Number</strong> *:</label>
      <input type="text" required="required" id="Contact_Phone_Number" name="Contact_Phone_Number" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="elqFormRow">
      <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;">
        <a name="eiel1718966"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <label for="Numbe_Of_Employees"><strong>Number of Employees</strong> *:</label>
      <select id="Numbe_Of_Employees" name="Numbe_Of_Employees">
        <option value="bet10and49">Between 10 and 49</option>
        <option value="bet50and99">Between 50 and 99</option>
        <option value="bet100and199">Between 100 and 199</option>
        <option value="ab200">Above 200</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="elqFormRow text-center">
      <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;">
        <a name="eiel1718967"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="elqFormRow text-center">
        <input type="submit" id="elqFormSubmitBut" class="orange_btn" value="Submit" checkrequired="true">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Click F12 and fix the console errors

Comment: the console errors are unrelated

Comment: `<form id="elqForm" method="post" name="elqForm" action="contactus.php">`
vs   `<form id="elqForm" method="post" name="elqForm" action="thanks.php" onsubmit="setTimeout(function(){if(document.querySelector){var s=document.querySelector('form#elqForm input[type=submit]');if(s){s.disabled=true;}}},100);return true;">`  they are not the same - your problem is java script not html

Comment: @shiddo I disagree - the console errors will break javascript on that page - you need to fix those or at least get those to disappear to start with

Comment: i put that script back. still not working. anyway in other contact us forms that i made there was no javascript in the form and it was working so i dont think the issues that i am having are javascript related

Comment: You are too fixated by the enter post not working why isn't the email address also not working - you have no java scripts in your segment but as repeated the page has fatal java script faults which is causing havoc - 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: WebForm_InitCallback is not defined
    at buyback.html:557 ` and `buyback.html:661 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (buyback.html:661)`   - comment them out and try again